# Iterating over a dictionary for tuples as keys

Tags: python, json, dictionary, key, tuples

Given a dictionary like the one below there are lists which I need to convert to keys for another dictionary.

```
{'timer': 100,
 'blocks': [[[5, 1], {'image': 'red.gif', 'points': 10, 'delete': True}],
            [[5, 2], {'image': 'red.gif', 'points': 10, 'bonus': 50, 'delete': True}],
            [[5, 3], {'image': 'red.gif', 'points': 10, 'delete': True}],
            [[5, 4], {'paddle_delta': 1, 'image': 'red.gif', 'points': 10, 'delete': True}],
            [[5, 5], {'image': 'red.gif', 'points': 10, 'delete': True}],
            [[5, 6], {'image': 'red.gif', 'points': 10, 'delete': True}],
            [[5, 7], {'paddle_delta': -1, 'image': 'red.gif', 'points': 10, 'delete': True}],
            [[5, 8], {'image': 'red.gif', 'points': 10, 'delete': True}]
            ]}
```

I need to see if a given set of lists already exist in the dictionary but can't seem to iterate through it.

Comment: Nope, there are *lists* in the dictionary. And so far, you don't seem to have *tried* to iterate through it.

Comment: Yeah I was stuck on 'how to' iterate through it. :(

Comment: Start with `for` and see where you get to? http://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F

Comment: Any hint on how to specifically find pairs in a list? Like for example, 

for k,v in dictionary :
     blah blah..

instead of finding for key and value in dict is there a way to find tuples in dict

Comment: *They aren't tuples*.

Comment: Excuse my poor wording, I thought they were lists(?) as I said in the first sentence. I meant how do I iterate to find a pair in a list..essentially converting lists into tuples. I'm pretty lost here so I apologise.

Comment: I've edited your question as it was far longer than necessary. In particular JSON is not relevant, you loaded the file fine. But I have to agree that you haven't shown any effort. Can you write a loop?

Answer (score -1):

If I am right, you are looking for itervalues() and iterkeys() methods of dictionary.

Examples:

```
for value in dictionary.itervalues():
      # do stuff with value

for key in dictionary.iterkeys():
      # do stuff with key
```

Edit: if you want to find tuples, use type() function. Example:

```
if type(key) is tuple:
    # do stuff
```